# Can I pass/access primitive data types (float,double,int) from another view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have two classes of View Controllers....

View 1

### View 2

### View 1

```
@interface BillDataEntryViewController : UIViewController {

    double x;
    double y;
```

//It is a big file but only showing which is necessary..
       }

//I have not declare any Properties nor I have synthesize it?

---

View 2

In another View I am creating an Object of view1 called objView1

but I am not able to access **objView1.double** ?  Why..

Comment: Because objView1.double is private.  Make it @public and you can access it.  Or add a property, as others have suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add properties for each ivar and synthesize them.
Then you can call: `objView1.x` or `objView1.y`

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) double y;
```

Answer (score 3):

retain cant be given for primitive types. but u can synthesize them.

Comment: Correct, you can only `retain` pointer type, but you can `assign` them.

Answer (score 3):

You should read up on [objective-c's properties](http://www.theocacao.com/document.page/510). Specifically the modifiers that you can give when specifying them in a .h file. However, as a rule of thumb :

1. For objects that you want to keep a reference to use `retain` - this will call retain on each object that you give it (it will also call release on the previous one for you!)

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *view;
   ```
2. For primitive data types use `assign` - this will just set your variable to the value you give it :

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, assign) float myFloat;
   ```
3. For things that have a mutable subclass use `copy` :

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myString;
   ```

   Option (3) is for things like NSString, NSData, NSURL, NSSet, NDictionary etc - basically 
   anything that has a Mutable version (i.e. NSString has an NSMutableString).
4. `readonly` if you don't want anyone to be able to change your data - this works for both pointers and primitive types.

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, readonly) double myDouble;
   @property (nonatomic, readonly) UIView *myView;
   ```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, passing values between two views is a bad idea. You should use a ViewController for that.

Moreover, you should make the vars accessible to other objects by creating getters (either by writing methods or by declaring ans synthesizing properties).

Comment: He calls his viewcontrollers view1 and view2 so he is using viewcontrollers.